# How to Change CSV Objects to JSON in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to change csv file output to array of objects, i am using node-xlsx library to get values of the csv file and i am trying to change it to array of Json object

Example csv file

```
var csvData = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
  [5, 6, 7, 8]
];
```

JSON file

```
var data = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
  },

  {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 7,
    d: 8,
  },
];
```

Comment: https://csv.js.org/ ?

Comment: This question really doesn't have anything to do with CSV *or* JSON.  I'd recommend removing those aspects from your question and simplifying this down to just what you're trying to do.  You've already parsed the data into the appropriate structures.  Now, you just need to zip the array of keys into an array of objects by key/value.  A simple loop will do.

Comment: yes you are right, what i want to do is, to change the array objects to json (csvData to data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of json or csv, you just need to move the data from the first array to a key-value data type.
I would use a loop such as this:

```
data=[]; 
for(var i=1; i<csvData.length; i++) {
    var obj={};
    for(var j=0; j<csvData[0].length; j++) {
        obj[csvData[0][j]]=csvData[i][j];
    }
    data.push(obj);
}
```

Then you can use JSON.stingify(data) to convert it into a JSON string